# why does the checkbox gives issues with state?

Tags: reactjs

In the `render()` function i have the following code to generate checkboxes

```
var cbCollection = this.state.cbData.map(function(elem, index) {

    var x=<span><label><input type = "checkbox"  name = "cbCodes"  id = "cb-{index}" value={elem.Id} checked={true} disabled={false} />{elem.DiagCodes}</label><br /></span>
    return x;

})
```

it generates the `checkboxes` but i cannot `uncheck` them from the UI they are frozen, how do i fix this?

Note: currently i have hard coded the check state assume the check state also comes from database. in this case how to make the checkboxes checkable and uncheckable?

**UPDATE:**

I have modified the code like this:

```
//
    getInitialState:function(){
    return{
        data1:[],
        data2:[],
        cbData:[],
        cbCheckState:false
    }
},
    UpdateCheckbox:function(elem){
alert(elem.IsSelected);
        this.setState({cbCheckState:elem.IsSelected});
    },
render:function(){
    var cbCollection = this.state.cbData.map(function(elem, index) {
        //this.setCheckboxValue(elem.IsSelected);
        var x=<span><label><input type = "checkbox"  name = "cbCodes"  id = {'cb-'+index} value={elem.Id} checked={this.state.cbCheckState} disabled={false} onChange={this.UpdateCheckbox(elem.IsSelected).bind(this)}/>{elem.DiagCodes}</label><br /></span>
        return x;

    })

return({cbCollection})    
}
```

it now it does not show the checkboxes and IE throws the error

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'state' of undefined or null
>   reference

internally code does some AJAX call to get data from DB and DB returns data to `dbData` array.

**update: 2**
here is the function updateCheckbox()

```
UpdateCheckbox:function(elem){
    alert(elem.IsSelected);
    this.setState({cbCheckState:elem.IsSelected});
},
```

alert prints undefined when i manually click on checkbox

[image: checkboxes successfully generates]

[image: when checked manually alert() shows undefined]

update 3: with updated UpdateCheckbox() still when clicked shown undefined

```
UpdateCheckbox:function(elem){

    elem.IsSelected = ! elem.IsSelected
    alert(elem.IsSelected);
   // this.setState({cbCheckState:elem.IsSelected});
},
```

render():

```
var cbCollection = this.state.cbData.map(function(elem, index) {
    //this.setCheckboxValue(elem.IsSelected);
    var x=<span><label><input type = "checkbox"  name = "cbCodes"  id = {'cb-'+index} value={elem.Id} checked={this.state.cbCheckState} disabled={false} onChange={this.UpdateCheckbox.bind(this,elem.IsSelected).bind(this)}/>{elem.DiagCodes}</label><br /></span>
    return x;

}.bind(this))
```

**update:4**
updated the render():

```
var cbCollection = this.state.cbData.map(function(elem, index) {
    //this.setCheckboxValue(elem.IsSelected);
    var x=<span><label><input type = "checkbox"  name = "cbCodes"  id = {'cb-'+index} value={elem.Id} checked={this.state.cbCheckState} disabled={false} onChange={this.UpdateCheckbox.bind(this,elem)}/>{elem.DiagCodes}</label><br /></span>
    return x;

}.bind(this));
```

still it does not check checkboxes for DB checked values but when i manually check alert() shows **true** but another weird things is when i hit OK of the alert() the checked checkbox becomes unchecked

update 5:now the DB check get checked but still when i click OK of alert the manually checked checkbox gets unchecked

```
  var cbCollection = this.state.cbData.map(function(elem, index) {
        //this.setCheckboxValue(elem.IsSelected);
        var x=<span><label><input type = "checkbox"  name = "cbCodes"  id = {'cb-'+index} value={elem.Id} checked={elem.IsSelected} disabled={false} onChange={this.UpdateCheckbox.bind(this,elem)}/>{elem.DiagCodes}</label><br /></span>
        return x;

    }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a variable on checked and make function onClick or onChange that change that variable on true or false

```
 var cbCollection = this.state.cbData.map(function(elem, index) {
        //this.setCheckboxValue(elem.IsSelected);
        var x=<span><label><input type = "checkbox"  name = "cbCodes"  id = {'cb-'+index} value={elem.Id} checked={this.state.cbCheckState} disabled={false} onChange={this.UpdateCheckbox.bind(this,elem.IsSelected).bind(this)}/>{elem.DiagCodes}</label><br /></span>
        return x;

    }.bind(this))
```

That is what i think is the best way to do it  !! I don't know from where come that cbData, but that is the way to do it .. !

```
                UpdateCheckbox:function(index){
                this.state.cbData[index].IsSelected = !this.state.cbData[index].IsSelected;
                this.setState(this.state.cbData);

            },
                render:function(){
                var cbCollection = this.state.cbData.map(function(elem, index) {
                //this.setCheckboxValue(elem.IsSelected);
                var x=<span><label><input type = "checkbox"  name = "cbCodes"  id = {'cb-'+index} value={elem.Id} checked={this.state.elem.isSelected} disabled={false} onChange={this.UpdateCheckbox.bind(this,index)}/>{elem.DiagCodes}</label><br /></span>
                return x;

            }.bind(this))

                return({cbCollection})
            }
```

Comment: what if their check states are coming from DB, in ths case what is the event handler that is best suited?

Comment: I don't understand you... its the same you need to bind that field checked to some variable doesn't matter if its from database or some where ... like that you write true on checked that checkbox always will be checked..

Comment: in your code you have written the bind(this,i) what is the 'i' variable here is the the handleChange() function's input parameter?

Comment: It is your index in the map function

Comment: i have updated OP but now it wont even display the checkbox list

Comment: You need to bind this on the function ... see i update my answer ,bind(this) on the map function and on the onChange...

Comment: I update it again and i think that is the best way to do it what you want to do

Comment: its a progress now the checkboxes shows, but they dont show their check state though cus DB has four checkboxes as checked. i have noticed this when i click a checkbox it shows an alert() with undefined. i beleive this alert() is the alert() in UpdateCheckbox()

Comment: Lets go some where to chat and i will try to help you

Comment: Ok first  in checked write only elem.isSelected that will check that element that in the database is check..

Comment: cbData contains an array that gets populated from an ajax call so i dont know why you pass the index and get value from that index in array to compare becuase elem has a property IsSelected this value is from DB and when i checked it contains either true/false so i basically need to set the state of cbCheckState using that

Comment: i have updated code with my current UpdateCheckbox() functtion

Comment: It is the same what you want to pass.. ok pass the elem .. and in the function set   elem.isSelected = ! elem.isSelected .. that variable cbCheckState i dont see for you use but it is useless

Comment: Ofc it will print you undefined if in the elem dont have that field...its ok that and now you need to set it like that "  elem.isSelected = ! elem.isSelected "

Comment: sorry man this is kind of weird why u need to compare the same variable with the same variable   elem.isSelected = ! elem.isSelected

Comment: You dont compare it you set it .. For example if its false.. you set it on true ..if its true you set it on false .. that is the point to change the checkbox on false and true when you click it

Comment: i have updated code in OP but still no luck same undefined error

Comment: still it does not check checkboxes for DB checked values but when i manually check alert() shows **true** but another weird things is when i hit OK of the alert() the checked checkbox becomes unchecked i have updaeted the OP with code change

Comment: checked={elem.isSelected}      change that field.. i told you wow :D

Comment: now the DB check get checked but still when i click OK of alert the manually checked checkbox gets unchecked i have updated OP

Comment: Yea now the only thing that you need to do is to change that field in that element in the database and here i cant help you ;xx sorry .. but in the 
UpdateCheckbox  you need to change database element..

Comment: two questions i want to ask 1. if i put a button how do i get all the checked checkboxes's values 2. ReactJS requires alot of coding specialy the checkbox seems bit hard. i have seen some reusable components written from reactjs so just like in Jquery JStree control i could use it. When it comes to reactJS do developer write their own reusable controls eg: compoenent to generate checkboxes or do they download reusable components from online and import them as child components?

Comment: what do you mean by changing the database element?

Comment: With the button is easy you just map that array you want and do that you want to do with this variables...second i dont know.. i dont think that checkbox is hard you just need to see how exactly work and it's amazing easy ..and 3-th  that array "cbData" idk how you get the data in it.. but in the function... elem.isSelected = ! elem.isSelected ..you change only that object value.. but in the database his value on that col.. it still false.. so for that next render it will take again that false and will unchecked .. so you need to send a request to database to change that col on that elem..

Comment: sorry man still confused started to learn reactJS since last week. the checkboxes only gets data for them from DB to display and put those checkstates. But the user still be able check/uncheck them but by check/unchecking will not trigger a DB update. the DB update should be done by a button click. so im still confused about your last comment on change the element name. please do explain and put it as an answer so i can give points and you deserve it you were actively participated on this : )

Comment: im calling the ajax from  componentDidMount() and in it im calling getData() which internally calls ajax. i dont need to send a request to the backend when user uncheck / check a checkbox. but i have intentions to send data to back end using a button click. in it i need grab all checked checkbox;s values and send them. How do i fix this check/uncheck problem im really happy to publish my code